# Problems with Ajax request in Chrome

Tags: php, ajax, google-chrome, request, response

I have a website that uses ajax requests as POST / GET to PHP services.

Testing it in Google Chrome, SOMETIMES (not always) the ajax requests are success (viewed using Charles), but in Google Chrome still in pending and this issue blocks my website.

In all other browsers there is no problem, but I've tried it using Chrome in different PCs and the problem still happens.

> The Chrome version is: 43.0.2357.130 m with no installed extensions.

There are no more than 1 request in the same time, and I use the jquery `$.ajax` method to do it:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "dynamic url...",
        data: {...},
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
        ...
        },
        error: function (e) {
        ...
        },
        complete: function () {
       ...
}});
```

I also tested it putting console.log on each ajax event but nothing printed.

This webservices are running in my own VPS, so maybe it is a PHP.ini misconfiguration or apache. I use .htaccess to do webservice redirections but it seems that is not the problem.

Can you help me? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please use method post
method :"POST"

Comment: Thank you, but I've tested using method: "POST" and the problem still happens. :(

Comment: are you return json array? if yes than use   dataType: "json",

Answer (score 0):

Using the code bellow still not work:

$.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "dynamic url...",
        data: {...},
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
        ...
        },
        error: function (e) {
        ...
        },
        complete: function () {
       ...
}});

Normally it happens when I call more than 5 requests sequentually after refreshing the page.